# How should I read 花弁?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

How should I read 花弁? I came across it in this sentence from ねじまき鳥と火曜日の女たち by 村上春樹.

> テーブルの上には紫色の木蓮の花弁が雨に打たれてはりついていた

大辞泉 has these two entries, which leads me to believe 花弁 is more officially correct as a way of writing かべん than of はなびら.

> か‐べん【花弁・花×瓣】
>   はな‐びら【花△弁・花△片・×瓣】

On the other hand, I feel like I've heard the word はなびら more often in speech.

Comment: 'A short story by Haruki Murakami' is sort of a vague context. Can you tell us which story, or better yet show us the paragraph in question?

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both readings are possible. はなびら is a yamato-kotoba (wago) and thus much more common as a word, but it tends to be spelled as 花びら to avoid confusion. For reference, [this lyrics search](https://www.uta-net.com/) knows 3,338 songs that contain `花びら` and 203 songs that contain `花弁`. For this reason, when I see 花弁 in all-kanji, I personally read it かべん most of the time. かべん sounds relatively stiffer, but IMHO it's not strange in a serious literary work. But this is basically a matter of taste, and I know almost nothing about Murakami's writing style. His fans may think differently.

Answer (score 0):

村上春樹's style is basically spoken language in daily life. So はな‐びら is better.